# Using a Search Cursor to calculate a new field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool

I am new to ArcPy. What I am essentially trying to do is use ArcPy to look through a column in a table and if it is between a range to print a value in a *new* corresponding column. I assume I am going to be using a search cursor to iterate a loop something like:

```
table = ("file path to table")
field = ("name of column")
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
for row in cursor:
    row.getValue(field)
         if ((field >0) & (field < 10)

          *in new column print 1*??
```

I have four different ranges I need it to run the column through, but do not know how to have it place the numbers from the calculation in a new field... Do I need to use the CalculateField_management tool instead?

Comment: Rule #1 for ArcPy newbies: Forget that `arcpy.SearchCursor` exists (Update and Insert as well). Only use the Data Access (`arcpy.da`) cursors.  But yes, this sort of update is really a two-line Select by Attributes/Calculate Field kind of thing.

Comment: After some help from my professor, he says to "first create a column, then look for records that fulfills a certain criteria, and then append a new attribute to the record"... is this similar to the select by attribute and calculate field or would it be better to use select by attribute and then append?

Comment: That's a different task than Select and Update, the (correct) answer below won't solve this task either.

Comment: So if I'm reading the bottom answer correctly, that runs through a column and "erases" the value and prints a new one if it is between my range?

Comment: Yup, just like a Select/Calc would.

Answer (score 3):

SearchCursor is only returning rows, you cant change your data with it. For updating you need [da.UpdateCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

> UpdateCursor establishes read-write access to records returned from a
>   feature class or table.

```
import arcpy

table = r"C:\folder\data.gdb\table123" #Change
fields = ["column1, column2"] #Change to match your field names

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if 0 < row[0] < 10: #row[0] = first field in fields
            row[1] = whatever you like #index 1 = second field in list
        elif 10 < row[0] < 20:
            row[1] = something
        #insert more elifs here
        else:
            continue
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Better to `else: continue` so unnecessary writes are not performed (faster).

Comment: As written, `10` will fall through the cracks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
import string

## workspace and variables
env.workspace = (r"D:\Grad_School\Programming\Final\output.gdb")

##variables
intable = "name of table"
#new field for calculation
arcpy.AddField_management(intable, "calculation", "SHORT")
fieldname = "Field You Want To Look At"
expression = "getClass(!fieldname!)"
codeblock = """def getClass(fieldname):
if fieldname <= 5000:
    return 1
elif fieldname > 5000 and fieldname < 20000:
    return 2
else:
    return 3"""
# execute CalculateField tool, populate new column
arcpy.CalculateField_management(intable, "calculation", expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)
```

Comment: Ahh, so the "append" you wanted wasn't an INSERT but an ADD COLUMN.  When working with tables, using the right jargon can improve understanding.